# Cannot understand how fixed point representation work?

Tags: floating-point, programming-languages

How 5.5 represented in fixed point

Will it be like

a) 0000 1011 ( 101.1 )

b) 55 -> 0011 0111

Cant understand fixed point representation or how they work..I am sorry if the question above is a stupid one...

Comment: These articles should explain it fairly well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @ti7 Those are floating point, not fixed point.

Comment: For fixed point, there has to be a fixed position for the binary point. What is it in your case?

Comment: If you really want to read wikipedia, read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic.I think it explains the concept pretty well. You simply scale an integral value by a fixed number to get decimals. Usually the scale is a power of 2, but it doesn't have to be. Some code also uses a power of 10 to scale by. It is not something "physical", it is merely a matter of interpretation.

Comment: Note that there is not one single fixed point. How the value is a matter of definition. Both 101.1 and 55 can be fixed point. 101.1 scales by 2 and only has one bit for the decimals, which would be pretty useless. 55 would scale by 10. If you scale by 10000, 5.5 would be represented as 55000, and 3.72 as 37200.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, in a fixed-point representation, you have some number of bits, say 16, and you designate a “radix point” (like a decimal point but for whatever base you are working with) to be at a fixed position. For example, with eight bits, we most commonly interpret them as an integer, so these bits:

```
01010111
```

represent 87. With fixed point, we might say that the radix point is between the fifth and sixth bits, as if they were:

```
01010.111
```

Then these represent 10.875 (10⅞ or 87/8).

The radix point does not actually appear in memory; we just remember to interpret the bits this way.

Fixed-point is useful when you want to work with values that are both smaller and more precise than integers using the same number of bits. E.g., instead of working with -128, -127, -126,… -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,… 126, 127, we want to work with -16, -7⅞, -7¾,… -⅜, -¼, -⅛, 0, ⅛, ¼, ⅜,… 15¾, 15⅞. The choice of where to put the radix point depends on what suits the needs of your application.

Processors might have some instructions to help you work with fixed-point values, but often simple integer arithmetic is used. We just have to remember that, if a pattern of bits represents the value *x* when interpreted as an integer, it is actually *x*/*q* in fixed-point, where *q* adjusts for where we put the radix point. (With three bits after the radix point, *q* is 2<sup>3</sup> = 8.)

When adding or subtracting numbers fixed-point numbers, we can just use integer arithmetic instructions. This is because *x*/*q* + *y*/*q* = (*x*+*y*)/*q*. So adding (or subtracting) two integers that we implicitly divide by *q* gives the same result as adding the integers already divided by *q*.

However, when we multiply *x* and *y* using an integer multiplication instruction, the result we get back is as if the radix point were in a different place. This is because *x*/*q* • *y*/*q* = (*x*•*y*)/*q*<sup>2</sup>. So, when multiplying, we have to shift bits in order to get the correct answer. For example, consider these two values:

```
00001.100 (12/8)
00010.100 (20/8)
```

The product of these is (12/8) • (20/8) = 240/64 = 30/8 = 3¾. If we multiply them with integer multiplication, the 16-bit result is:

```
00000000 11110000
```

Because of the multiplication, there are now six bits after the implicit radix point instead of three, so this value is:

```
00000000 11.110000
```

To adjust for that, software working with fixed-point will often shift the bits to put the radix point back in the designated location, and then it might discard the extra high bits. So we would have:

```
00000000 00011.110
```

and then:

```
00011.110 (3¾)
```

Instead of shifting the bits to reset the radix point after multiplication, software can also keep the bits, remembering that the radix point is in a new location.

In large part, fixed-point arithmetic is calculating using the numerators of fractions where the denominators are built into the software. (And so you could even use denominators that are not powers of two if that suits your purposes, but that makes re-adjusting the numbers after multiplication more difficult, since it involves division instead of simple bit-shifting.)

Answer (score 0):

Think of a mechanical counter, likes the ones used some time ago in gasoline dispensers or in the odometers in cars. Each wheel has the same number of symbols. When the wheel on the right finishes a full rotation, the next wheel hops to the next symbol.

[image]

The decision as to where the decimal point should be depends only on the desired scale. To change the reading from kWh to mWh one only need paint three more squares red. The machine and the counting mechanism would remain the same, and only our interpretation of the symbols would change.

To produce the same in binary (or any other number base) one only need change the number of symbols in the wheels. If there is a decimal point, and where it lies is just a matter of interpretation.

Kilometers or hectometers, anyone?

[image]